# Merging csv columns in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a csv file (called let's say file1.csv) converted via an excel file with:

```
ssconvert file.xlsx file1.csv
```

Now I'd like to create another csv file (`file2.csv`) from `file1.csv` with only two columns `title` and `description`.
`title` may be blank, but `description` to be created by merging, let's say, column 5-7 from `file1.csv` via a script in Bash.

Example:

`file1.csv`:

```
field5, field6, field7 
how, are, you
```

`file2.csv`:

```
title, description
(empty), how are you
```

Comment: If title is going to be blank, why have it at all? Or is it supposed to be calculated from the original file? If so, how?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the following `cat file1.csv |cut -d "," -f 1-2,4`. The `-d ","` separates the output from `cat file1.csv` into columns. The `-f 1-2,4` selects columbs 1-2 and 4.

Answer (score -1):

The question of where the title field comes from aside, assuming your CSV is simple without things like commas inside of quoted fields to worry about, maybe something like:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print "title,description"; next }
         { printf("(empty),%s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3) }' file1.csv > file2.csv
```